$f:[0,1] \to R$ is measurable but not Lebesgue integrable. Is $g(x,y) := f(x) - f(y)$ is also not Lebesgue integrable on $[0, 1] × [0, 1]$?
Let's take $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ as a measurable and not Lebesgue integrable function. Is that true that the function $g$ defined by the formula $g(x,y) := f(x) - f(y)$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$?
I am sure it's true, because if $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable, then, there must be some place in $[0,1]$ where it "blows up" to $-\infty$ or $\infty$. Because of that, it must be true that $g(x,y)$ is also not Lebesgue integrable since those places where $f$ "blows up" cannot cancel each other because we would have $\infty - \infty$ and that can't be interpreted in any way.
I think that this intuition must be correct, but I don't know how to show that. I didn't find any elegant way of doing so while looking on that forum.
Edit:
Let's assume that $g$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0, 1] × [0, 1]$. Then from Fubini's theorem, we have that:
$$ \int \int_{[0,1][0,1]} g(x,y) \ \lambda_2(x,y) = \int \int_{[0,1][0,1]} f(x) - f(y) \ \lambda_2(x,y) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left[ f(x) - f(y) \right] \ dx dy = $$
$$= \int_0^1 f(x) \ dx -  \int_0^1 f(y) \ dy = \infty - \infty$$
Is that enough to say that we got to a contradiction and conclude that $g$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[0, 1] × [0, 1]$?

Perhaps try Fubini's theorem.

If it is Lebesgue integrable, then $\int |f(x)-f(y)|dx<\infty$ for some $y$ (by Fubini's Theorem).

I don't think that's the correct way to approach it. The integral of $f$ is not finite (since the function is not Lebesgue integrable). Therefore I think that the Fubini's theorem can't be applied here. @GEdgar

But it's not Lebesgue integrable - both sides of implication that does occure or not (that's the question asked in the post) are not Lebesgue integrable. @geetha290krm

Note that "not Lebesgue integrable" does NOT necessarily imply $\int_{[0,1]}f, \text{d}\lambda=\infty$. The only thing you can actually infer is that $\int_{[0,1]}f^+, \text{d}\lambda=\infty$ or $\int_{[0,1]}f^-, \text{d}\lambda=\infty$.

So I just need to wrap my original thinking with absolute value? @math-jl

If $f$ is not integrable, then neither is $f-\alpha$ for any constant $\alpha$ since the measure of the whole space is finite.
In particular, for any $y$, $\int |f(x)-f(y)| dm(x) = \infty$ and hence $g$ is not integrable.

If "integrable" means only that the integral is defined and not necessarily finite:
Lebesgue integral for functions of type $D\to\Bbb{R}$ is defined as:$$
\int_Df(x)\mathrm d\mu = \int_Df_+(x)\mathrm d\mu - \int_Df_-(x)\mathrm d\mu 
$$
where $f_+$ and $f_-$ are the positive and negative parts of the function respectively and $\mu$ is the used measure. If $f$ is measurable, then both these integrals exist. So the only way how $\int_Df(x)\mathrm d\mu$ may not exist is when both $\int_Df_+(x)\mathrm d\mu$ and $\int_Df_-(x)\mathrm d\mu$ are infinite.
We have to prove that $\int_{D^2}g(x,y)\mathrm d\mu^2$ does not exist. Let $D_+$ be the part of $D$ where $f$ is positive and $D_-$ be the part of $D$ where $f$ is negative. We can now give lower bounds on the integrals of the positive and negative parts of $g$, namely:$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{D^2}g_+(x,y)\mathrm d\mu^2&\geq
\int_{D_+×D_-}f_+(x)\mathrm d\mu^2+\int_{D_+×D_-}f_-(y)\mathrm d\mu^2=\\&=
\mu(D_-)\int_{D_+}f_+(x)\mathrm d\mu+\mu(D_+)\int_{D_-}f_-(y)\mathrm d\mu=\\&=
\infty+\infty\\
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
\int_{D^2}g_-(x,y)\mathrm d\mu^2&\geq
\int_{D_+×D_-}f_-(x)\mathrm d\mu^2+\int_{D_+×D_-}f_+(y)\mathrm d\mu^2=\\&=\mu(D_+)\int_{D_-}f_-(x)\mathrm d\mu+\mu(D_-)\int_{D_+}f_+(y)\mathrm d\mu
=\\&=\infty+\infty
\end{aligned}
$$
Basically, we select the rectangles where both $f(x)$ and $-f(y)$ are positive in the first case, and $f(x)$ and $-f(y)$ are negative in the second case. $\mu(D_+)$ is the measure of the set on which the function is positive. This must be bigger than zero. Similarly $\mu(D_-)$ must be also bigger than zero.
It turns out that both the bounds are infinite, therefore $
\int_{D^2}g(x,y)\mathrm d\mu^2
$ does not exist.
I did this for an abstract case. For your concrete case, use $D=[0,1]$ and use the Lebesgue measure as $\mu$.
If the definition of "integrable" also requires the integral to be finite:
Here, I will offer only a proof for your case. It would be more complicated to do it in general and there would be more conditions on when the statement holds.
For the case when both $\int_{[0,1]}f_+(x)\mathrm d\lambda(x)$ and $\int_{[0,1]}f_-(x)\mathrm d\lambda(x)$ diverge, refer to the case above. Now let's assume that $\int_{[0,1]}f_+(x)\mathrm d\lambda(x)$ diverges and $\int_{[0,1]}f_-(x)\mathrm d\lambda(x)$ converges. For the other way around, the proof would be very similar.
Now we can define two subsets $A, B\subset[0,1]$ this way: $A = \{a | a \in [0,1], f(a)>t\}$, $B = \{b | b \in [0,1], t>f(b)>0\}$, where $t = \max(0, 1+\mathrm{ess inf}_{x\in[0,1]}f(x))$ (essinf stands for essential infimum). Note that $\int_Af_+(x)\mathrm d\lambda(x)=\infty$ while $B\subset[0,1]$, such that $\int_Af_+(x)\mathrm d\lambda(x)<\infty$ and both subsets have a nonzero measure. It also holds that $\forall x\in A, y\in B: x-y > 0$.
Now we can give a lower bound on the integral of the positive part:$$
\int_{[0,1]^2}g_+(x,y)\mathrm d\lambda(x,y)\geq\int_{A×B}g_+(x,y)\mathrm d\lambda(x,y)=\int_{A×B}g(x,y)\mathrm d\lambda(x,y)=\int_{A×B}(f(x)-f(y))\mathrm d\lambda(x,y)
$$
The integrand is positive in this region, as the $f(y)$ is always smaller than $f(x)$ in the given ranges. We can now easily show that the integral of $f(x)$ is infinite, while the integral of $f(y)$ is finite. Therefore, $\int_{[0,1]^2}g_+(x,y)\mathrm d\lambda=\infty$ and the function $g$ is not integrable.

That's not quite correct. The function $f$ not being not integrable is equivalent to $f_+$ or $f_-$ integrating to infinity (not both). Also note that $\mu(D_\pm)$ could vanish (which could ruin your lower bounds).

@SeverinSchraven If $f$ is measurable, then both $\int_Df_+(x)\mathrm d\mu$ and $\int_Df_-(x)\mathrm d\mu$ should exist, no? And if only one of them was infinite, then the integral would be simply $\pm\infty$, therefore the function would be integrable. What am I missing here?

Integrable means that both $\int f_+ d\mu$ and $\int f_- d\mu$ are finite. Thus, $f$ is not integrable means one of the two is infinite.

Thanks for this remark. I fixed my answer accordingly.
